# imagemagick convert.exe error

Tags: php, imagemagick

My code to convert planets.png to planets.jpg

```
<?php 
exec("convert planets.png planets.jpg");
?>
```

Which is not working just showing blank page.

i have installed imagemagick as it is showing in phpinfo() [View here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRJlG.png)

Is here any other configuration remaining to run that imagemagick code.

Error message

```
[Sat Jul 28 20:16:11 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP 1. {main}() D:\\wamp\\www\\test\\into.php:0 Invalid Parameter - planets.jpg
```

Comment: check the logs. not working without an error is not possible. either a path is wrong or write permissions on destination folder.. or other things

Comment: I don't know how to check logs

Comment: Most likely it is a path issue. Sure you execute the code in the directory where the image file is ? You have to specify paths otherwise.

Comment: you seem to be on windows with apache... check error.log in apache folder

Comment: give full path of convert like /usr/bin/convert and give it a  try

Comment: `[Sat Jul 28 20:16:11 2012] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] PHP 1. {main}() D:\\wamp\\www\\test\\into.php:0 Invalid Parameter - planets.jpg `

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is why is important to have the error message. With it we can search for answers.

You have inadvertently run the Microsoft Windows program called convert.exe, rather than the ImageMagick program of the same name. The Windows convert.exe program is used to convert a system boot disk from MS-DOS "FAT" format to NTFS format. As such it can only be used one time in the life of a system. [Source](http://imagemagick.sourceforge.net/http/www/FAQ.html#C19)

## Solutions

You can

- rename either the MS convert.exe or the ImageMagick convert.exe
- revise your PATH to put ImageMagick's convert.exe ahead of MS convert.exe
- edit your Windows Registry as explained in http://savage.net.au/ImageMagick/html/install-convert.html

Comment: thx.. but is just a google search when you know what to look for. and the error message is very important

Comment: you should make another question.. the idea is to have simple questions - answers for other users that will get into the same problem

Answer (score 3):

```
exec("convert planets.png planets.jpg");
```

This is exact equivalent of opening a command prompt window and executing this.

Also, as @Elzo pointed out, `convert.exe` is a built-in executable, so you will need to specify the entire path of the executable. (I'd suggest this rather than renaming either executable).

```
exec("\"C:\\Program Files\\..\\convert.exe\" planets.png planets.jpg");
```

Answer (score -3):

The ImageMagic extension for php has nothing to do with ImageMagics 'convert' command. It is separate software. Sure you have installed command installed on your system ? Try manually using it in a shell.

What shows up inside the phpinfo() is the ImageMagic extension. That one does not bring a 'convert' cli utility and has to be used quite different to what you attempt.

Comment: He seems to have installed it to the path, as shown in his image.

Comment: I know little about MS Windows, indeed. Both packages are installed as one package in such systems ? Oh my...