# The image contain error with imagick

Tags: php, imagick

```
<?php

header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');

// If 0 is provided as a width or height parameter,
// aspect ratio is maintained
$image->thumbnailImage(100, 0);

echo $image;

?>
```

is giving error The image “http://localhost/test/into.php” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.Solve this please?

Comment: possible duplicate of [imagemagick convert.exe error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11702187/imagemagick-convert-exe-error)

Comment: What does the image contain when you view it in a text editor? I bet there's a PHP error message in there.

Comment: he edited the other question.. I asked him to put this question separate

Comment: I see the same error here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8675336/cmyk-to-rgb-using-php

Comment: @Pekka in log file it is showing class imagick not found

Comment: That's your problem then. You will need to install the imagick library. http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.installation.php

Comment: but i have already see here http://i.stack.imgur.com/IRJlG.png

Comment: Nope, that's only the system-wide PATH setting. It doesn't mean the library is installed. It seems like the only way to get this library on Windows is to recompile PHP - ugh....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image is created at 0 px height and probably invalid format. Try and see [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.thumbnailimage.php).

```
$image->thumbnailImage(100, 100);
```

Answer (score 2):

Please read details in commented lines

```
<?php

//drawing stuff that creates $image

ob_get_clean(); //this statement is what mine was lacking before I could get it to work properly
header("Content-type: image/png");
echo $image;
```

Comment: In my case `ob_get_clean()` was needed too, until I noticed a hidden `print "<pre>";` statement earlier in my code. Still this solution can save a lot of time.